# What is a blocking semaphore in Java?

Tags: java, semaphore

Based on my understanding, a blocking semaphore is initialised to zero rather than one, working in a manner that any thread that does a P(S) operation will block until released by V(S) first.

Can anyone explain this mechanism with an example, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a **blocking** semaphore

The [`java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) class supports both blocking and non-blocking operations.

> a blocking semaphore **is initialised to zero rather than one**

You set the initial number of permits. If you set `permits` to `1` (`new Semaphore(1)`), you can `acquire` once before you `release`.

- If the value is `> 0`, some `acquire`s may happen before `release`s.
- If the value is `<= 0`, some `release`s have to occur before an `acquire` is called.

It's documented in [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#Semaphore-int-):

> This value may be negative, in which case releases must occur before any acquires will be granted.

---

```
class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Semaphore s1 = new Semaphore(0);
        s1.acquire(); 
        // the thread is disabled
        // no permit is available
        // a blocking operation

        final Semaphore s2 = new Semaphore(1);
        s2.acquire();
        // returns immediately
        // one permit was available

        final Semaphore s3 = new Semaphore(0);
        if (s3.tryAcquire()) {
            // a non-blocking operation
            // returns false immediately
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#Semaphore(int)) of the Semaphare class:

> permits - the initial number of permits available. This value may be negative, in which case releases must occur before any acquires will be granted.

And:

> Each acquire() blocks if necessary until a permit is available, and then takes it. Each release() adds a permit, potentially releasing a blocking acquirer.

So, assuming you init with **-1**, the semaphore will block `acquire()` calls until a `release()` comes in.

In that sense: you simply do a `semaphore = new Sempahore(-1)` and you will find that `semaphore.acquire()` will block until some other thread has done a `semaphore.release()` call.

That is all there is to this.